# Wrong recipient error while using SignIn after switching Dialogflow agents

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-signin

I made a new Dialogflow agent and transferred my code, which was working on the previous agent, to the new one. One of the main things my agent does is account linking using the SignIn helper. I also got a new clientID in my Google Assistant console and pasted it in my code.

Now however I get this error in my NGROK: `{"error":"Wrong recipient, payload audience != requiredAudience"}`

I assume the problem is related to Dialogflow's clientID, which I replaced in my code after transferring to a new agent. The problem? I have no idea what the error means and the internet isn't helping me understand it too much, since I'm not advanced at this yet.

This is how I link my clientID as described here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in

```
const app = dialogflow({
    clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    debug: false,
  });
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be/have experience with this error? I know it isn't in my code, since it worked before.

Comment: I've ran into this error when I had request verification active on my webhook. This uses the clientID to verify requests to only accept calls from your action's Google project, so any calls that aren't from your Google project will be blocked. Although I don't see it in your setup here, maybe the docs will help you further a bit more. Apart from this i'd recommend double checking if all client ID's are the correct ones. https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/reference/rest/verify-requests

Comment: Correction: Verification uses the Google project ID, not the clientID. I couldn't edit my earlier comment anymore :/

Comment: @Jordi I looked into it and found out from the source you linked that it was my Firebase key, not my Google Assistant key that was wrong. Big facepalm, but you helped me resolve it. So thank you very much :D!